# PGP on linux suse

Tags: linux, encryption, pgp

The following script works on a windows server :

```
pgp --encrypt TESTDIR\TESTPgp.txt -r issucnc
Exit
```

How would I make the same code to work on a linux server if I wanted to transfer a file from linux to windows? Do I need to install something for this?

**Or is PGP already installed and available in linux? How would I know if it is?**

I have done my assignment. I have read things on PGP but the only thing that is clear to me is that it is used for encryption. On what exactly the output of the above code, I don't know.

Please help me. I would really appreciate your help and understanding that I am a complete noob at this.

Thank you so much.

Comment: This isn't "code" and, as such, does not belong here.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the most common OpenPGP implementation is GnuPG:

```
gpg --recipient issucnc --output TESTDIR/TESTPgp.txt.pgp --encrypt TESTDIR/TESTPgp.txt
```

or a shorter version

```
gpg -r issucnc -o TESTDIR/TESTPgp.txt.pgp -e TESTDIR/TESTPgp.txt
```

Of course, you have to `gpg --import` the public key of *issucnc* first.